# Jquery validate only partially working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So I'm using jquery validate to validate a form, and it's working for the most part, but my confirm password input isn't doing anything.  It doesn't show that it's a required field, when I'm telling it to be required just like the rest of the fields, and the equalTo: method I'm using doesn't work, however I don't think the equalTo: method is the problem because the required:true doesn't work either.

Here's my JQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D)
        {
            var JQUERY4U = {};

            JQUERY4U.UTIL =
            {
                setupFormValidation: function()
                {
                    //form validation rules
                    $("#user").validate({
                        wrapper: 'div',
                        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
                        debug: false,
                        rules: {
                            username: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 5    
                            },
                            password: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 5
                            },
                            confirmPassword: {
                                required: true,
                                equalTo: "#password"
                            },
                            termsOfService: "required",
                        },
                        messages: {
                            username: {
                                required: "Please enter a username",
                                minlength: "Must be at Least 5 characters",
                                },
                            password: {
                                required: "Please enter a password",
                                minlength: "Must be at least 5 characters"
                            },
                            confirmPassword:{
                                required: "Confirm Password required",
                                equalTo: "Passwords don't match"
                                },
                            termsOfService: "please accept our terms of service",
                        },
                        submitHandler: function(form) {
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
            $(D).ready(function($) {
                JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
            });

        })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

and here's my jsp page form

```
<form:form commandName="user" method="POST">
Username: <br><form:input path="username"/><br><br>
Password: <br><form:password path="password"/><br><br>

Confirm Password: <br><input type="password" id="confirmPassword"/><br><br>

Terms of Service<form:checkbox path="termsOfService" id="termsOfService" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 15px;"/><br><br>

<input type ="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit"/><br><br>

</form:form>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSP but i think both password and confirm password inputs should be like this `<form:password path="password" id="password"/>` and `<input type="password" path="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, I'm not familiar with JSP but very much familiar with jQuery validation plugin,

First your are missing `id="password"` to password input

```
<form:password path="password" id="password" />
```

and then `path` to confirm password input

```
<form:password path="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"/>
```

jQuery validation plugin to set the rules based on inputs `name` attributes or in JSP `path` so not able to find `confirm password` because of missing `path` and `equalTo` failing because you binding it with `"#password"` but no `id="password"` given in `password` input

Comment: Ok, but now I get an exception, because I added path to confirmPassword, and nothing happened, so I changed it `<form: path="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPassword"/>`, and now I have an "Invalid property 'confirmPassword' of bean class..."

Comment: `id="confirmPassword"` is unnecessary, try removing that

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I should have said that at the beginning